# Taylor Expansion in time and space

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to prove the order of accuracy of a numerical scheme to solve the one way wave equation. Here's a snipit:$$\frac{(v_m^{n+1}+v_{m+1}^{n+1})-(v_m^{n}+v_{m+1}^{n})}{2k}$$
I'm expanding the value of my grid function around $(t_n,x_m)$ for time step, k, and space step,h. The expansions are:
$$v_m^{n+1}=\phi_m^n+k\phi_t+\frac{k^2}{2}\phi_{tt}+O(k^3)$$ $$v_{m+1}^{n}=\phi_m^n+h\phi_x+\frac{h^2}{2}\phi_{xx}+O(h^3)$$
$$v_m^{n}=\phi_m^n$$

My question is how to expand $v_{m+1}^{n+1} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
v_{m+1}^{n+1} = \phi_m^n+k\phi_t+h\phi_x+\frac12 k^2 \phi_{tt} + kh\phi_{tx}+\frac12 h^2 \phi_{xx} +O(k^3) + O(k^2h)+O(kh^2) + O(h^3)
$$
Most of the time, those four third-order terms are lumped together and one says "plus third-order (in $k$ and $h$) errors."

Answer (score 0):

$v_{m+1}^{n+1}=\phi_m^n+h\phi_x+k\phi_t+\frac{1}{2}(k^2\phi_{tt}+h^2\phi_{xx}+hk\phi_{xt})+O((\sqrt{h^2+k^2})^3)$.